# clang-format break before "unlikely" unexpectedly

Tags: macros, clang-format

It is my former code:

```
if unlikely(a > b) throw "a > b";
```

after clang-format, it becomes:

```
if
    unlikely(a > b) throw "a > b";
```

Which option in .clang-format to stop the break before "unlikely" ?

Comment: `if (unlikely(...))` should fix that and make your code less strange.

Comment: @Mat Thanks, it helps!